# Using for each to convert String to integer is not working

Tags: php

I have a function written to convert String to integer(using a for each loop).
Function:

```
function prepare_client_data($data)
{  
foreach ($data as $index=>$value)
 {
    if($index<1) continue;
    $data[$index]['3']=(int)($value[$index]['3']); 
    $data[$index]['18']=(int)($value[$index]['18']); 
    $data[$index]['20']=(int)($value[$index]['20']); 
    $data[$index]['22']=(int)($value[$index]['22']);
    $data[$index]['25']=(int)($value[$index]['25']);
    $data[$index]['30']=(int)($value[$index]['30']);  
}
```

but this function doesn't work and convert all of strings to **int 0** 

i wonder that when i do the same thing out of `foreach` it works:

```
$data['3']['20']=(int)($data['3']['20']);
echo $data['3']['20'].'test';
```

Can someone help me out.I tried cracking it.
No progress.

Comment: can you add what's inside `$data`?

Comment: Post with Sample input ,,

Comment: Something wrong in `$data[$index]['3']=(int)($value[$index]['3']); ` $data... = $value ... ?

Comment: In echo example of outside foreach loop you are doing `$data[xxx] = (int)$data[xxx]` but in foreach loop you are doing `$data[xxx] = (int)$value[xxx]` use $data in front of (int) inside foreach loop too.

Comment: You should not post a Question with simple type. Which wastes everyone's time and gives nothing to new user visiting the question first time !

Comment: why $value didnt work in this case ?it has the same content with $data

Comment: you should do `$value['3']` and not `$value[$index]['3']`

Comment: tnx so much $value['3'] is working fine sry about my poor question:(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all you are missing one curly braces. Here is the solution you neeed

```
function prepare_client_data($data) {
    foreach ($data as $index => $value) {
        if ($index < 1)
            continue;
        //echo ($value['3']);
        $data[$index]['3'] = (int) $value['3'];
        $data[$index]['18'] = (int) ($value['18']);
        $data[$index]['20'] = (int) ($value['20']);
        $data[$index]['22'] = (int) ($value['22']);
        $data[$index]['25'] = (int) ($value['25']);
        $data[$index]['30'] = (int) ($value['30']);
    }
    return $data;
}
$data=prepare_client_data($data);
```

or

```
function prepare_client_data($data) {
    foreach ($data as $index => $value) {
        if ($index < 1)
            continue;
        $data[$index]['3'] = (int) ($data[$index]['3']);
        $data[$index]['18'] = (int) ($data[$index]['18']);
        $data[$index]['20'] = (int) ($data[$index]['20']);
        $data[$index]['22'] = (int) ($data[$index]['22']);
        $data[$index]['25'] = (int) ($data[$index]['25']);
        $data[$index]['30'] = (int) ($data[$index]['30']);
    }
}
```

It'll only work if you have numeric value rather than alpha

Comment: Wrong !! Curly braces would immediately give him ERROR !! His program is working!! Just he forgot to use braces in the Question while posting!

Comment: either way he missed the one brace during posting the quesstion

Comment: I know but its Typo ! Read `It convert all of strings to int 0` ! If he had missed a brace there would be Error without showing Any output